# Duplicate column names after JOIN in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Consider two tables:

```
t1          t2
A   B       A   C
------      -----
1   2       3   4
```

I run this code:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON 1=1");
print_r(mysql_fetch_all($q));
```

And get this result:

```
array(
  A => 3
  B => 2
  C => 4
)
```

In all the cases I tried such thing, the value from the latest joined table goes to array (index A). The question is, can I count on that?
I know about aliases, but it would be much easier for me if I could know how Mysql+php behave in such case. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: why on earth are you joining on ON `1=1`

Comment: @J-Dizzle: To get a result with a row, I assume. And it shows, from which of the columns with the same name the value is taken.

Comment: I think (and hope) the 1=1 join was just for this example. I also don't think the tables are named t1 and t2 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()
```

then you can count on it:

From [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

> **Return Values**
>
> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the
> last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the
> same name, you either need to access the result with numeric indices
> by using mysql_fetch_row() or add alias names. See the example at the
> mysql_fetch_array() description about aliases.

**Note**

Please look at the red box. If you write new code for new projects consider moving to mysqli or PDO. And take the inpact of the deprecation of the mysql_* functions to your existing projects into account.

Comment: Thank you. Although I am still not sure about which column is 'last' when php gets the result from mysql, I figure it's possible to use `select t1.*, t2.*` to make it explicit.

Comment: The columns of the table in the FROM clause are first, followed by the columns of the table in the JOIN clause. Within each table, the columns are in the same order that you will see if you run `DESC t1`. The column order is t1.A, t1.B, t2.A, t2.C, and is consistent. In your query, t2.A will always be returned, replacing the value from t1.A , as it is the last out of those 2 that have the same name!

Comment: The same behaviour is in the newer mysqli functions also.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify aliases to help out here:

SELECT *, t1.a AS t1_a FROM ...

Aliases also help if you have operations in the select clause, eg: SUM(a*b) AS line_total